# Coordinates of a vector FFT

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I was reading a paper about DFT, at the end he got the relations $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}W_n \cdot y$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt N}W_n \cdot Y$, where $y$ is a vector and $Y$ is the coordinates of that vector in the basis. $W_n$ stands for the transformation matrix.
Later, the author shows how to reduce the following into smaller matrices but I don't really understand what is he doing nor how is he doing it.

\begin{align*}
W_4 \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_1\\y_2\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_2 \end{bmatrix}
 +\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\\omega&\omega^3 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
\\
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&\omega^4\\1&\omega^6 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_2 \end{bmatrix}
 +\begin{bmatrix} \omega^2&\omega^6\\\omega^3&\omega^9 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_2 \end{bmatrix}
 +\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\omega \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
\\
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_2 \end{bmatrix}
 -\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&\omega \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step, the author is just exploiting some associativity of the matrix-vector product. For instance, the first two rows of $W_4y$ are:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&1\\ 1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_1\\y_2\\y_3 \end{bmatrix} 
&=
\begin{bmatrix} y_0+y_1+y_2+y_3\\ y_0+\omega y_1+\omega^2y_2+\omega^3y_3 \end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix} (y_0+y_2)+(y_1+y_3)\\ (y_0+\omega^2y_2)+(\omega y_1+\omega^3y_3) \end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix} y_0+y_2\\ y_0+\omega^2y_2 \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} y_1+y_3\\ \omega y_1+\omega^3y_3 \end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\omega^2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_0\\y_2 \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\\omega&\omega^3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_3 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh ok, now i get it thanks. i will continue by myself from here